# Is regex a good way to test a url

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm trying to test the validity of a url entered with php5. I thought of using regex, but assuming that it works correctly all the time, it only solves the problem of the url being syntactically valid. It doesn't tell me anything about the url being correct or working.

I'm trying to find another solution to do both if possible. Or is it better to find 2 separate solutions for this?

If a regex is the way to go, what tested regexes exist for urls?

Comment: even testing if a url exists "now" does not mean it will exist "when" you want to render/use it later.

Comment: Why are you testing if a URL is valid? Generally as the web developer, don't you know ahead of time that the URL is valid? In most CMS or other systems valid URLs are either files or database entries, but checking that would depend completely on your setup. Some more information would help guide an answer, be specific about your predicament.

Comment: It's probably too lenient for what you want to do, but take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Will you only have HTTP URLs to validate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of cracking my head over a regex (URLs are *very* complicated), I just use [`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), and then attempt to ping the URL using [cURL](http://www.php.net/curl):

```
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== false)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($status_code >= 200 && $status_code < 400)
    {
        echo 'URL is valid!';
    }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, pinging only tests whether the domain exists, not if the full URL is available.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: good point. Edited my answer to use cURL instead, which should be more viable.

Comment: I'd also add HEAD method there. Someone could point you to some 1GB sized file and your server will happily download it all otherwise. Besides, its not good to download something if you only want to check if it exists - thats what HEAD is for.

Comment: @Daniel Kluev: good point as well, added the respective options now.

Comment: wrap it in a function, this way you get to brand it.

Comment: @Daniel not all servers will give HEAD.

Comment: @Gordon +1 for the phrasing, but I'm yet to see such a server. The RFC specifically says "This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity..."

Comment: HTTP redirects do not necessarily mean the URLs are invalid

Comment: @Artefacto Agreed, just mentioning that it could potentially lead to false results when some admin disabled it.

Answer (score 3):

For validation
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

For checking if it exists... well you need to try to access it actually.

Answer (score 2):

In order to test that a URL is 'correct or working', you'll need to actually try and interact with it (like a web browser would, for example).

I'd recommend an HTTP library for Perl like [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-5.836/lib/LWP/Simple.pm) to do so.

Comment: So I should break it into 2 tasks then.

Comment: Absolutely. You are asking two completely different questions, for example: is http://google.com a valid HTTP URL? ...and... can I HTTP GET the resource defined by http://google.com over the network right now? Another example of how the questions differ - the answer to the first question will be the same over time, the answer to the second changes if your network goes down.

Answer (score 2):

RegExLib is good place to go for Reg Ex expressions

http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

1. Check that the URL is valid using a very open regex or `filer_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`.
2. Do an `file_get_contents` on the url and check that `$http_response_header[0]` contains a `200` HTTP resoponse.

Now, that's dirty, sure there is some more elegant version using curl and stuff.

Comment: you could just use [`get_headers`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that function. PHP is full of surprises ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of 'check that an external file exists' functions on the [`file_exists()` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

Answer (score 1):

i would use regex to go about solving this problem and i hate regex. This tool however makes my life so much easier... check it out >> http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1):

Pinging a URL to see if it is a valid URL is nonsense!

- What if host is down?
- What if the domain is not ping-able?

If you really want to do a "live" testing, better try to **resolve the URL by using DSN**. DNS is more reliable then PING or HTTP.

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

echo $ip;
?>
```

**But even if this fails URL can be valid. It just have no DNS entry.** So it depends on your needs.