# URL Validation?

Tags: php, regex, url-validation

Does anyone know an up to date regular expression for validating URLs? I found a few on Google but they all allowed junk URL's i.e (www.google_com) when testing.

My regular expression knowledge is not so vast, so I would hate to put something together that would fail under pressure.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is regex a good way to test a url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408839/is-regex-a-good-way-to-test-a-url). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php

Answer (score 4):

You can use the filter functions in PHP

```
$filtered = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Answer (score 1):

Not every problem should be answered with a regex.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Hm… Cite: "This function is ***not*** meant to validate the given URL, it only breaks it up into the above listed parts." ;-)

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think by "validate" they mean "check that there's an actual page there". If it's not a valid URL, I'd imagine the splitting algorithm would choke.

Comment: @ceejayoz: That's of course nonsense. An URL can be valid without pointing to an existing resource. The function will not make an HTTP.