# various url validation using regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I validate the following urls:

1. http:www.google.com/test
2. http:www.google.com
3. www.google.com
4. google.com

In all the above cases, my regular expression will return true and also I want to extract the url from the first case.How we cam implement this feature?

Comment: Do you want to test that a url is one of the four you mention (if so, try ==)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408839/is-regex-a-good-way-to-test-a-url

Comment: @carlpett, I see no PHP tag in his question

Comment: My point was rather that regex is the wrong tool for url validation

Answer (score 0):

My stab at it:

```
var match = url.match(/(http:\/\/www\.google\.com\/test)|http:\/\/(www\.)?google\.com/);
if(match){
  alert("found it");
  if(match.length>1 && match[1]){
    alert("captured it "+match[1]);
  }
}
```

Apparently, a capturing group in only one side of the `|` makes the capturing group to be there but undefined

PS: I have added slashes to the URLs, shouldn't they be there?